# Does GAE-Search document field-name length affect the data size (and hence cost)

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search, gae-search

Does GAE-Search keep the field name with each document or at the top level?
If it keeps (and transmits) field names with each document, I will need to minimize the field name length to reduce storage and network cost, else I can keep the names more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We store field names with each document.  So theoretically you could save a bit on cost by keeping the names short.  But it seems like a tiny factor to be worrying about: generally the size of fields is dominated by content, compared to names.  And of course this is an undocumented internal implementation detail, so it could change in the future.

By the way, I am indeed a "Google Search API engineer" (as you put it).

Comment: Thanks Alan. For me, most of the data is broken into small field values. That gives me option to search and rank by fields. I use gae-search for combining geospatial and text search and use customised ranks. I think this detail should be part of the docs, since it can affect storage cost for use cases like mine.